# How to fix React's useEffect infinite loop even with the empty brackets?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, use-effect, react-context

I have encountered this problem yesterday, it worked, but after I implemented onClick event on the button to open a new custom window. From that moment my app went to infinite loop.

I tried console.log() which showed me unlimited number of request to the API.
To be more precise, every API call works until I go to the Dashboard page.

I use ContextAPI for my state management. Here's code:

HOTEL ContextAPI:

```
const [hotelData, setHotelData] = useState({
        data: {},
        loaded: false,
        reviewData: {},
        reviewsLoaded: false,
        detailData: {},
        detailLoaded: false,
    })

    const getHotelsData = () => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        axios.get(`${HOTEL_DATA}`, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        })
            .then((res) => {
                const { data } = res
                setHotelData((previousData) => ({ ...previousData, data, loaded: true }))
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                if (error.response) console.error(error)
                if (error.request) console.error(error)
            })
    }
```

Dashboard.js:

```
const { hotelData, getHotelsData, getSpecifiedReviews, getSpecifiedHotelDetails } = useContext(HotelContext)
    const { data, loaded, reviewData, reviewsLoaded, detailData, detailLoaded } = hotelData || {}

    const { loggedIn } = loginUser || {}

    useEffect(() => {
        getHotelsData()
    }, [])


    return (
        <main className="dashboard-wrap">
            <section className="heading-box">
                <h1 className="heading">Hotels</h1>
            </section>
            {/* Fetching data if it is loaded. */}
            {!loaded ? <FontAwesomeIcon className="spinner" icon={faSpinner} /> : <section className="data-box">{data.map((item) => (
                <section className="data">
                    <h1 className="data-name">{item.name}</h1>
                    <section className="data-location">
                        <h2 className="data-city">{item.city},</h2>
                        <h2 className="data-country">{item.country}</h2>
                    </section>
                    <section className="stars-box">
                        <p>{Array(item.stars).fill(<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStar} />)}</p>
                    </section>
                    <section className="image-box">
                        <img className="data-image" src={item.image} alt={`Hotel: ${item.id}`} height="500" width="800" />
                    </section>
                    <section className="date-time-box">
                        <Moment format={'dddd / MMMM / YYYY'}>{item.date}</Moment>
                    </section>
                    {getSpecifiedHotelDetails(item.id)}
                    <section className="description-box">
                        {/* <p className="data-description">{item.description} <button className="description-details" onClick={windowOpen}>More details</button></p> */}
                    </section>
                    <section className="review-box">
                        <button onClick={() => getSpecifiedReviews(item.id)} className="review-btn">
                            Show Reviews
                        </button>
                        {
                            reviewsLoaded ? <div>{reviewData.map((reviewItem) => (
                                <div>{reviewItem.id === item.id ? (
                                    <div>{reviewItem.message}</div>
                                ) : null}</div>
                            ))}</div> : null
                        }
                    </section>
                </section>
            ))}</section>}
        </main>
    )
```

Comment: Where is the code for `windowOpen`?

Comment: @jmargolisvt that appears to be irrelevant, it's commented out anyway

Comment: @jmargolisvt It is commented out, I'm trying to fix the infinite loop, which triggered above when mapping data. Even if it started looping after I added it, I commented it, thinking maybe it was the actual problem, but nothing same happens.

Comment: any chance the component is being mounted/unmounted by the parent based on the data?

Comment: UseEffect is used correct ,I think component is rerendering. .put alert in UseEffect if it's being called multiple times even when ,empty array is passed, then component remounting everytime

Comment: @andrewgi Did check that, nothing either.

Comment: @sudhakarselva It alerts me once, but data still reloads. I'm getting too many requests my app is lagging a lot!

Comment: Maybe bcuz of getSpecificdetails method which u have inlined it

Comment: @sudhakarselva Oh, I missed to delete that part, thank you. You solved my issue! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: No probs. Happy coding!!!...